# sed to replace user@hostname

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Find what:

```
DEFINER=`abc_de43`@`123.234.56.345`
```

Replace with:

```
DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%`
```

File content:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`abc_de43`@`123.234.56.345`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`def_test_db`@`localhost`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`admin_test_db`@`XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`d123_test_db`@`hostname`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`def_344_db`@`12.123.23.123`
```

Command I am trying:

```
sed  's/`*`@`*`/`dbadmin`@`%`/g' /tmp/vwdefTest.txt
```

Comment: Rather than `*`, use `.*` (with a dot prefix)

Comment: In general `x*` means zero or more occurances of _x_, so `* does not look very sensible.

Comment: please update the question to show the expected result (corresponding to the 5-line sample input file)

Comment: can `DEFINER ....` show up in any lines that do *not* start with `CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED`, and if the answer is 'yes' then ... please include sample line(s) in the input and the expected result

Comment: You said you want to match ```DEFINER=`abc_de43`@`123.234.56.345` ``` but then your code is trying to match ````*`@`*````. Please [edit] your question to clearly state your actual requirements and show the expected output to clear up the confusion as we're all making different assumptions about what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

`* will only match 0 or more ` characters in regular expressions, remember that `*` is not a glob match here.

You may use this `sed` command instead:

```bash
sed -E 's/(DEFINER=)`[^`]*`@`[^`]*/\1`dbadmin`@`%`/' file

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%``
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%``
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%``
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%``
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%``
```

Here:

```
`[^`]*`
```

will match a text wrapped in ` on both sides.

If you want to save changes in the input file then use:

```bash
sed -i.bak -E 's/(DEFINER=)`[^`]*`@`[^`]*/\1`dbadmin`@`%`/' file
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but output is DEFINER=dbadmin@`%``. There are two quotes in the end.My expectation to have only one quote.

Comment: Not quite: You should write _will only match **0** or more...._  A `+` would match one or more.

Comment: sed -E 's/(DEFINER=)`[^`]*`@`[^`]*/\1`dbadmin`@`%/' /tmp/vwdefTest.txt . This is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

sed doesn't understand literal strings so any sed solution will fail given various characters in your search and/or replacement strings [without careful escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed), but awk does.

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 's=index($0 RS," " old RS) { $0=substr($0,1,s) new } 1' \
    old='DEFINER=`abc_de43`@`123.234.56.345`' new='DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%`' file
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`def_test_db`@`localhost`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`admin_test_db`@`XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`d123_test_db`@`hostname`
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`def_344_db`@`12.123.23.123`
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want your expression to include `DEFINER=` if you want to match that specifically. In any case, what you seem to be missing is a `.`. The `.` means "any character" and the `*` means one or more occurrences of it.

Try:

```
sed 's/DEFINER=`.*`@`.*`/DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%`/g' /tmp/vwdefTest.txt
```

Comment: After trying above sed command output is CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%`))); . It is not expected result.Thank you for for working on this issue.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you want. What's the expected output you are after?